# Issue with rotating image while saving in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, rotation, signature

**Actual Behaviour :**

I am supposed to implement signature pad in landscape-right mode along with a timestamp of signature drawn. Then take a screenshot of the view, and save it in document directory (iOS) or external directory (Android) in portrait mode by rotating it. I was successful in implementing signature screen in landscape-right mode using `transform: [{rotate: '90deg"}]` css property, and react-native-signature-capture, save the captured screenshot of signature along with the timestamp of signature drawn in local directory using react-native-view-shot and convert it into base64 format using react-native-fs.

But the saved screenshot is not in portrait mode and I'm trying to rotate the image while saving it in document directory (iOS) or external directory (Android) without using any modules. I also tried rotating the image while saving it using canvas context API but could not find way to access canvas in react-native to rotate image while saving it as canvas is HTML DOM related.

**Expected Behaviour :**

I'm supposed to save the signature drawn along with timestamp in document directory (iOS) or external directory (Android) in portrait mode as shown in below screenshot.

**Additional Resources :**

Code :

```
render() {
  return (
    <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      overflow: "hidden",
    }}>
    <StatusBar hidden={true} />
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 0.8,
        flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
        marginVertical: width / 18,
        overflow: "hidden",
      }}>
      <ViewShot
        ref="viewShot"
        style={[styles.viewShot, { transform: [{ rotate: this.state.bool && '90deg' }] }]}>
        {/* options={{ width: height, height: width }}> */}
        <SignatureCapture
          style={styles.signature}
          ref={sign => (this.signComponent = sign)}
          onSaveEvent={this._onSaveEvent}
          onDragEvent={this._onDragEvent}
          saveImageFileInExtStorage={true}
          showNativeButtons={false}
          showTitleLabel={false}
          showBorder={false}
          viewMode={'portrait'}
          square={true}
          backgroundColor={"white"}
          maxSize={800}
          rotateClockwise={!!true}
        />
        <View
          ref="timeRef"
          style={{
            width: width / 10,
            height: width / 3,
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              width: width / 1.8,
              height: width / 1.8,
              transform: [{ rotate: '-90deg' }],
              overflow: "hidden",
              paddingLeft: width / 18,
              paddingTop: width / 25
            }}>
            <Text style={styles.time}>{this.state.data}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ViewShot>
      <Image
        ref="imageRef"
        source={{ uri: this.state.imageUri }}
        style={{ transform: [{ rotate: '90deg' }] }}
      />
    </View>
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 0.2,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        overflow: "hidden",
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      }}>
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: Colors.darkGreen,
          width: width / 2,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          paddingRight: width / 25,
          paddingVertical: width / 37.5,
          transform: [{ rotate: '-90deg' }],
          overflow: "hidden",
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          hitSlop={{ top: 30, left: 50, right: 50, bottom: 30 }}
          onPress={() => {
            this.saveSign();
          }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: width / 18, color: Colors.white }}>Submit </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#5476ab',
          width: width / 2,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          paddingVertical: width / 37.5,
          transform: [{ rotate: '-90deg' }],
          overflow: "hidden",
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          hitSlop={{ top: 30, left: 50, right: 50, bottom: 30 }}
          onPress={() => {
            this.resetSign();
          }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: width / 18, color: Colors.white }}>Clear</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#73c5de',
          width: width / 2,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          paddingVertical: 10,
          transform: [{ rotate: '-90deg' }],
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          hitSlop={{ top: 30, left: 50, right: 50, bottom: 30 }}
          onPress={() => {
            this.onCancel();
          }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: width / 18, color: Colors.white }}>Cancel</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>


 );
}

_onSaveEvent(result) {

    this.setState({ signature: result.pathName, 
                    markResult: result.encoded });
  }

 _onDragEvent() {

    this.setState({ dragged: true });
  }

saveSign() {

    if (this.state.dragged === true) {
      this.setState({ bool: true });
      this.refs.viewShot.capture().then(uri => {
        this.setState({ imageUri: uri });
        console.log("uri123", uri);
         RNFS.readFile(this.state.imageUri, 
          'base64').then(image => {
          console.log("image123", image);
          this.setState({ sign: image }, () => {
            this.ChangeOrientation();
          });
        });
       });
      } else {
      Alert.alert('NALG', 'Please sign the signature 
      pad to submit');
      }

 ChangeOrientation() {

    this.props.getSignature(this.state.sign);
    this.props.setModalVisible(!this.props.modalVisible);
  }
```

*Screenshot of Actual Behaviour :*

[image]

*Screenshot of Expected Behaviour :*

[image]

**Environment:**

react-native : 0.61.1

react-native-view-shot : ^3.0.2

react-native-signature-capture : ^0.4.10

react-native-fs : ^2.16.2

Comment: can https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot/issues/273 be related?

Comment: I'm not using Expo SDK in my project. So my issue is not with Expo SDK. I'm woking on project created with react-native init project_name. Thanks anyway.

Comment: did you get any solution for this....
i am facing a similar issue

Comment: the thing is when an image is converted to Base64 it gets its orientation changed, thus i too am facing this issue and am unable to find a solution, `react-native-image-picker` has this solution, but the code is a bit complex

Answer (score 0):

```
const showImagePicker = () => {
    const options = {
      title: i18n.t('issueReport.form.photoSelection'),
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images',
      },
      allowsEditing: true,
    };

    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
      const { originalRotation } = response
      console.log('Response = ', response);
      console.log('originalRotation = ', originalRotation);

      if (originalRotation === 90) {
        setOriginalRotation(90)
      } else if (originalRotation === 270) {
        setOriginalRotation(-90)

      }
      setSelectedImageFile(response);

      if (response && response.height === 3000) {
        setLandscape(true)
      }

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        const source = { uri: response.uri };

        console.log('Image Path', source);
        // You can also display the image using data:
        // const source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };
        setSelectedImage(source);
        setPhotoSelectVisible(true);
      }
    });
  };
```

For more detail
https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/655